# How to apply Dependency injection when not all dependencies are always used?

Tags: dependency-injection, dependencies, logic, code-injection

I am trying to understand DI. Since I don't write unit tests (yet), the biggest advantage for me is the decoupling of classes and the management/control of dependencies.

But there's one question: what if I have a class A (controller), that instantiates class B (a listener), and class B will - under certain circumstances - instantiate class C (a mailer)?

According to the DI principle, I have to create C and pass it to B. What if I don't need C during a request? Do I have to create some logic for the Dependency Injection first?

Answer (score 1):

> According to the DI principle, I have to create C and pass it to B. What if I don't need C during a request? Do I have to create some logic for the Dependency Injection first?

This shouldn't be a problem because [injection constructors should be simple](http://blog.ploeh.dk/2011/03/03/InjectionConstructorsshouldbesimple/):

> An Injection Constructor should do no more than receiving the dependencies.

When you do this, object creation is really fast and [reliable](http://blog.ploeh.dk/2011/03/04/Composeobjectgraphswithconfidence/), and it doesn't matter whether or not a consumer always uses all of its dependencies.

Comment: Okay thanks, it helped me to grasp the actual approach of DI a bit better. However with my own application, I still have the problem that certain objects, like a client object, are dependencies of many of the classes. So I end up passing those objects around. I was wondering whether this means that I have a wrong concept?

Comment: That's hard to comment on. You will have to give concrete examples.

Comment: My app generates a user interface that displays user data. For this, I need an user object. Since this user object is such a central part of the app, I need it in different places, such as sending emails, or displaying user information in the UI. Therefore, I'm passing the object "around". This has also led to a cicular dependency; the controller dependencies need the user object, but the user object needs the properties of the controller. If this is still too abstract, I might start a new question with my code examples.

Comment: Please do start a new question. Feel free to post a comment here that links to that new question.

Comment: Here it is, thanks in advance: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50544477/circular-and-recurring-dependencies